# Tagging D&D Next / 5e playtest questions

Tags: discussion, tags, dnd-5e

How should we be tagging D&D Next questions during the playtest(s)? Right now we have questions tagged with a random combination of [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next), [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e), and [playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playtest).

Comment: [Related] [Can we rename \[dnd-next\] to \[dnd-next-playtest\] before it's released?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3530/321)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are problems with the two existing system tags:

- [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) may or may not be the name of the later edition.
- [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) also may or may not be the name of the later edition.
- Both refer to a system that doesn't exist yet, therefore the current questions are about rules that may or may not actually be in a game system of that name in the future.

I propose that we create a [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) tag to cover these questions. It is:

- **Accurate and future-proof**: It accurately reflects the name of the system currently being asked about, and will keep these questions and answers segregated from future questions about the next edition of D&D without having to clean up the tags later.
- **Discoverable**: It will be mostly discoverable as the asker types in a tag. Anyone typing in "playtest" will also have the chance to notice that we have a dedicated D&D Next playtest tag. It won't intercept people who are tagging [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) and avoiding the "Next" name entirely, but those questions also appear to be a minority (1, as of this typing).

That should resolve the problems with the existing tags. Manual retagging should be enough to handle incoming questions. A [dnd-5e-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e-playtest) synonym to [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) would nicely close the discoverability gap mentioned above. We might consider a temporary synonym from [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) to [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) (to be removed once/if "D&D Next" ever refers to a non-playtest ruleset), but only if manual retagging proves to be troublesome.

(To forestall one objection, we can't synonym [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) to [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) or any other proposed tag because we have existing questions about "D&D 5e" from before Next was announced. (And I'll leave aside the question of whether we should have speculative [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) questions as a can of worms that's best considered separately from this issue.))

Answer (score 2):

Lets just use [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) and commit to adapting the rules questions as the playtest changes. Its silly to create this tag soup for a game that is eventually going to be a single entity.

synonym [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) and [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) into it and you have discoverability.

Comment: Given that entire game concepts may be changed or removed such that current questions may be meaningless if edited like that, I don't think that would work.

Answer (score 1):

I propose that we synonym [dnd-next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next) and [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) for now, and make sure that all current posts are ALSO tagged [playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playtest).  After all: if this works then D&D isn't likely to be the only game that will go through a public playtesting period such as this nor the only one that will have significant changes when playtesting happens.  This way, when the next game down the line starts playtesting we can tag it with [nextgamedowntheline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nextgamedowntheline) and [playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playtest).

This would make it obvious that these questions were asked during the playtest period, while not over-cluttering the tagspace with extra [nextgamedowntheline-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nextgamedowntheline-playtest) tags.

Comment: Would the playtest tag then be of independent interest, and what about questions related to playtesting in general - I doubt the people interested in playtesting as a subject in and of itself want to read all D&D5 rules questions.

Comment: @Thanuir Whether they want to or no, the playtest tag on its own has more utility then creating what amounts to an extra tag for every and each game that has a playtest.