# Tag-sorting: [dnd-5e] vs. [dnd-next-playtest]

Tags: discussion, tags, dnd-5e, playtesting

There's (at the moment of this writing) [about 29 questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22d%26d%20next%22%20%5Bdnd-5e%5D%20-%5Bdnd-next-playtest%5D%20is%3Aq) that mention "DND next", are tagged [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) and not tagged [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest).

Some of these questions need to be retagged for sure, and apparently, such an initiative has started as old questions have had their tags swapped in the last few days. Two examples from the last hours are:

- [Using 3d6 instead of d20 for D&D Next](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31709/using-3d6-instead-of-d20-for-dd-next)
- [Was Murder in Baldur's Gate a part of the D&D Next/5e playtest?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125303/was-murder-in-baldurs-gate-a-part-of-the-dd-next-5e-playtest)

To try to not overwhelm the main site with old questions and draw too much attention, we should stagger the re-tagging as needed, and possibly communicate which questions do or don't need attention further in this process.

Which of the questions demand immediate attention and which might need to stay 5e only?

[For the record: we're down to about 18 on 2022-09-10]

### Notes

D&D 5e was officially published in or around July/August 2014, so the cutoff date for easy sorting is, that most items asked before are most likely playtest material.

It might be possible that a considerable amount of [more than 100 questions asked before July](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D%20created%3A..2014-07%20is%3Aq). About [30-ish of that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdnd-5e%5D%20created%3A..2014-06%20is%3Aq) might need the Next Playtest tag but had it swapped in the [renaming to 5e](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3530/can-we-rename-dnd-next-to-dnd-next-playtest-before-its-released?noredirect=1&lq=1) - which would need to be reversed.

Comment: Related: [Tagging D&D Next / 5e playtest questions](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1514/52137), [Can we rename \[dnd-next\] to \[dnd-next-playtest\] before it's released?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3530/52137), [Revisiting whether D&D Next needs its own separate tag](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6554/52137)

Answer (score 5):

### Change the tag for questions *specific* to the playtest

To sum up the history, the D&D Next tag used during the playtest was merged into D&D 5e upon release and later split again, which left a lot of questions that were specific to the playtest still tagged as [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e). Those questions which are specific to the playtest, eg. about rules which were changed before release or about the playtest itself, should be tagged correctly.

Not all the questions that mention it are actually specific to the playtest. Doubly the questions from sept. 2014 and later are unlikely to be so. (But you know, read them and use your judgement)

### On immediacy

For the most part though, retags like this aren't a high priority. Usually it's fine to retag as it comes up (and there's lovely wiggle-room for what it means to come up). And since the playtest is over and not of great interest, the questions simply don't come up very often leaving them unretagged.

Since they've now come up, and there's not really that many of them, I think we're fine to fix them. Just for completeness though, I'll urge partaking users (and I'm probably going to among them) to show restraint with pacing so not to flood the homepage with 8 year old questions.

Comment: For the most part, I think you should find a few more places to squeeze "for the most part" into this answer.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov The dangers of posting an answer before you need to leave and thus don't have time to review nor edit for prose(?). For the most part though, the meaning parsed well :)

Comment: With great disappointment, I see you have done the opposite of what I suggested.